# Weird CSS effect with box shadows - how to solve?

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

See this example:

[image]

I have several boxes with white background and huge black, translucent box shadows that overlap the boxes above. However, this leads to an irritating behavior: While the white background gets darker through the overlapping box shadows, **nested objects, like text or other boxes, don't!**

Could anybody tell me why this occurs? I guess it has something to do with `z-index`. I would like prevent this - the nested objects should become darker as well. Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

---

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/xq20hvp4/3/

```
<div>Coloured text <span>Box with background</span></div>
<div>Coloured text <span>Box with background</span></div>
<div>Coloured text <span>Box with background</span></div>
<div>Coloured text <span>Box with background</span></div>
<div>Coloured text <span>Box with background</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 250px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Consolas, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
div span {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

Comment: You want the span to have the same effect? If so, change `background-color` to `transparent` for your `span` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because those elements are **on top of** the div with the shadow. In order to put them behind, you can use `position: relative;` on the background element and give it `z-index: 1`:

```
div {
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 250px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Consolas, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  /* Add this */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div .box {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wwz8usw/.

Comment: Did you add the wrong link? This fiddle appears to be the same as mine. Your code is fine. Thanks!   PS: Why are those elements on top of the box shadow? I still didn't get it...

Comment: because they are drawn one after each other and last is up front, if they overlap you'll see it better https://jsfiddle.net/xq20hvp4/5/ ( old ies use to do the opposite ... ), beside, to avoid hidding content, shadows won't overlay boxes unless not in static position

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/fd7tx2c2/

```
div {
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
```

[Z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

[Position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: You need to fork the fiddle in order to show changes.

Comment: Looks good! Can you tell me why these CSS properties are necessary?

Comment: in 3d there is an x,y,z axis. Z is the 3d axis meaning anything with a higher z-index will be closer to the user on a 3d axis therefore it will overlap anything with a lower z-index. Position is necessary to have in order to use z-index. I'll edit my answer with links that explain these things